# Failing to load libraries in the same directory

Tags: ruby-on-rails, ruby, ruby-on-rails-4, require

I have this file `wsbillingactionDriver.rb` in

`lib/f2b/billing_action/`

And in the same directory I have the file `wsbillingaction.rb`

The first one tries to require the second as following:

`require 'wsbillingaction.rb'`

But it fails and says: `cannot load such file -- wsbillingaction.rb`

Why does it happen?

Answer (score 0):

It might be an issue with your `$LOAD_PATH`

[From the Ruby docs](http://apidock.com/ruby/Kernel/require)

```
require(p1) private
Loads the given name, returning true if successful and false if the feature is already loaded.

If the filename does not resolve to an absolute path, it will be searched for in the directories listed in $LOAD_PATH ($:).
```

You could try `require './wsbillingaction'`

or `require_relative './wsbillingaction'`

If none of that works, you could could add the path that `wsbillingactionDriver.rb` is in to your `$LOAD_PATH`